# shell script that's equivalent to "alias mount='mount -t ext3"?

Tags: bash, command

Some 3rd party application executes "mount" and I want it to mean "mount -t ext3"

I know, normally this can be done by alias. 
But this is rather rare situation where I need something other than alias.

(it's related to cloud machine executes remote command on another machine.. somehow alias doesn't work)

I'm going to rename /bin/mount to /bin/mount_execute and create a script at /bin/mount.
when 'mount a b' is executed i'd like it to be translated to 'mount -t ext3 a b'

'mount a b' -> '/bin/mount a b' -> '/bin/mount_execute -t ext3 a b'
(where /bin/mount is the script that I am asking for)

Comment: If you are writing a separate script, just add `-t ext3` at the line of execution of `mount_execute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

mount_execute -t ext3 $@
```

was the script I needed.
Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

When `alias` doesn't work, you could change the `PATH` for said program, so that your mount script comes first; this way, you don't have to mess with /bin/mount (IMO a bit dangerous)

Comment: Assuming of course that the program uses "mount" and not a direct call to "/bin/mount", which I've seen programs do.